# Controlling when a footnote appears in beamer presentation

Tags: beamer, footnotes

In my beamer presentation, I have multiple slides of the form

```
  \frame{
  \frametitle{FRAME TITLE HERE}
  \begin{itemize}
  \begin{columns}
  \begin{column}{2in}
  \item \onslide<1->
  TEXT FOR ITEM 1 HERE WITH REFERENCE TO A FOOTNOTE USING \footnotemark
  \item \onslide<2-> 
  TEXT FOR ITEM 2 HERE WITH REFERENCE TO A FOOTNOTE USING \footnotemark
  \end{column}

  \begin{column}{1.6in}
  \onslide<1->
  ADD FIGURE 1 HERE
  \onslide<2->
  ADD FIGURE 2 HERE
  \end{column}
  \end{columns}

  \footnotetext[1]{TEXT FOR FIRST FOOTNOTE HERE}
  \footnotetext[2]{TEXT FOR SECOND FOOTNOTE HERE}
  \end{itemize}
  }
```

However, when I do this, *both* footnotes appear on slide 1, even though the \footnotemark for the second footnote appears in the main text on slide 2.  Ideally, I would like the second footnote to appear only when the second slide comes up.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Use `\only<2>{\footnotetext[2]{TEXT FOR SECOND FOOTNOTE HERE}}`

Comment: Thanks!  But what if I also have a 3rd slide and I want it to also be on the 3rd slide?

Comment: I guess \only<2-3> does the trick.  Great, thanks again!

Comment: Yes. `<2->` means *from 2 and go on*. `<2-3>` means *on 2 and 3*.

Answer (score 25):

In order to remove this question from the list of unanswered questions, here the comments turned into an answer.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

  \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{FRAME TITLE HERE}
    \begin{itemize}
            \item \onslide<1-> TEXT FOR ITEM 1 HERE WITH REFERENCE TO A FOOTNOTE USING \footnotemark
            \item \onslide<2-> TEXT FOR ITEM 2 HERE WITH REFERENCE TO A FOOTNOTE USING \footnotemark
        \item \onslide<3-> TEXT FOR ITEM 3 HERE
        \footnotetext[1]{TEXT FOR FIRST FOOTNOTE HERE}
        \only<2->{\footnotetext[2]{TEXT FOR SECOND FOOTNOTE HERE}}
    \end{itemize}
  \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want the footnote box to keep its size, not increasing every slide, use the following instead:

```
\footnotetext[2]<2->{TEXT FOR SECOND FOOTNOTE HERE}
```

Comment: I'd like a footnote to appear from the second slide onward (and nothing in the first slide) which this solution doesn't seem to support (I get a lonely "1" on the first slide in the footnotetext area).