# footnote positions using `\only<>`

Tags: beamer, footnotes

I have a beamer presentation where I use footnotes to list references.
[This post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/155893/controlling-when-a-footnote-appears-in-beamer-presentation) gives me how to control the appearance of footnote. However, as we can see in the answer, the footnote rule is "shifted up" when second footnote is typeset. 
How to overcome this (something like reserve space for 2 footnotes by default)

the MWE below is copy from the link given

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

  \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{FRAME TITLE HERE}
    \begin{itemize}
            \item \onslide<1-> TEXT FOR ITEM 1 HERE WITH REFERENCE TO A FOOTNOTE USING \footnotemark
            \item \onslide<2-> TEXT FOR ITEM 2 HERE WITH REFERENCE TO A FOOTNOTE USING \footnotemark
        \item \onslide<3-> TEXT FOR ITEM 3 HERE
        \footnotetext[1]{TEXT FOR FIRST FOOTNOTE HERE}
        \only<2->{\footnotetext[2]{TEXT FOR SECOND FOOTNOTE HERE}}
    \end{itemize}
  \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

  \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{FRAME TITLE HERE}
    \begin{itemize}
       \item \onslide<1-> TEXT FOR ITEM 1\footnotemark
       \item \onslide<2-> TEXT FOR ITEM 2\footnotemark
       \item \onslide<3-> TEXT FOR ITEM 3 HERE
       \footnotetext[1]{TEXT FOR FIRST FOOTNOTE HERE}
       \only<1>{\let\thefootnote\relax\footnotetext{~}}
       \only<2->{\footnotetext[2]{TEXT FOR SECOND FOOTNOTE HERE}}
    \end{itemize}
  \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you! the modification i had to do was add sufficient number of blank lines (as per the second footnote text size in this line: `\only<1>{\let\thefootnote\relax\footnotetext{~}}` instead of `~` i added `~\\~` or `~\\~\\~` depending on the size of the second footnote.

Comment: @okkhoy To get automatically the required space, you could try `\textcolor{white}{TEXT FOR SECOND FOOTNOTE HERE}`